# Rejection sampling from a Gamma distribution using a Cauchy proposal

Tags: self-study, gamma-distribution, parameterization, rejection-sampling, cauchy-distribution

i'm trying to find the parameters $ \gamma,x_0$ of a standard Cauchy distribution : $$T(x)= \frac{1}{(\pi \gamma (1+(\frac{x-x_0}{\gamma})^2))} $$
To perform rejection sampling from a gamma distribution: 
$$
G(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\lambda^\alpha \exp(-\lambda x)
$$
And i have seen than in several textbooks as Bishop's pattern recognition it seems like if is straightforward to derive those parameters to obtain the values $$x_0 = \frac{\alpha -1}{\lambda}$$ and $$\gamma^2 = 2\alpha-1$$ 
But so far i just have obtained $x_0$ by making equal the derivatives of T and G and solving for x, but for the $\gamma$ parameter i just dont know how to find it, because all the attempts that i have made leads me to polynomial equations of degree >=3 and irrational roots...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Common usage would have lower case for density functions and upper case for cdfs. Why are you setting derivatives to be equal? Is there some lower bound on $\alpha$?

Comment: (I can see a reason to set the derivatives equal, but if you're doing it for a different reason, that would be important to know). Oh, and is this for some subject?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b thanks for the clarification for notation, there are two main reasons to make equal these derivatives:
1) Setting the derivatives to be equal to see where they modes should be centered
2) Im not pretty sure of this ... but maximizing the proposal will maximize the reason $G/(mT)$.

Comment: And yeap, this is for an independent class on machine learning from a probabilistic perspective, following the Murphy's book of the same name, i have discussed this exercise with some people but we still trying to solve it.

Comment: This would fall under `self-study`. Please add the tag and [read the tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You'll need to lose one of your present tags to do so. I think `sampling` is redundant (given you have `rejection-sampling`), so I'd suggest replacing that one. If you follow those guidelines, you'll likely get some hints/guidance.

Comment: What do you do if $\alpha=0.8$?  Also note that the value you give for $x_0$ is actually just the mode of the gamma distribution. That might let you see what's going on.

Comment: (or rather, it's the mode as long as $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Then think about the second derivative at the common mode.

Comment: For this problem, I requested my corrections in the [PRML Errata Repository](https://github.com/yousuketakada/prml_errata). See my [preview file](https://github.com/yousuketakada/prml_errata/blob/6a65c919aeaac4f79224ecee8475631e3b128f83/prml_errata.pdf) for page 529-530.